# rpmbuild shows prelink:at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have one directory which i have updated to latest
Now when i try rpmbuild it shows

prelink: /pgsql/pgAdmin3/lib/libpng12.so.0.10.0: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking

how to remove all this non sense stuff(prelink)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated
There was no any such message before updating directory.The updated directory contains pgsql files

Answer (score 0):

Simplest disabling is to "rpm -e prelink". Otherwise "man prelink"